# FullCalendar load events with ajax that returns json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I have tried following this example http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/ but modified it for a json response.

The ajax call successfully returns an array of event objects however the callback on the array returns the error

```
 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

My code below is below

```
 events: function(start, end, callback) {
  jQuery.post(
    MyAjax.ajaxurl,
    {
        action : 'myajax-submit',
        data: {
            request: "tasks"
        },
        postID : MyAjax.postID
    },
    function( response ) {
        callback(response);
    }
   );
 },
```

Any help much appreciated

Alex

Comment: post more of your code. Most likely you have not defined MyAjax.postID or you have not passed in a callback at the time of invoking this.

Comment: the ajax call works fine and response contains the array of event objects. you are right the problem is with the callback as I don't understand them. I have not mentioned this callback anywhere else in my code

Comment: the function requires an argument for a callback - a function that will be called at return of the ajax call. That callback function will accept the ajax response and do what you want with it. You need to pass that function into this events function as its 3rd argument.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25444930/fullcalendar-how-to-load-all-events-on-calendar-using-ajax