# fullcalendar - How to load all events on calendar using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I want to load all events in full calendar using Ajax when the page loads.I am getting response from Ajax.But the event is not added in Full calendar.
here is my jquery code

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        theme: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultDate: '2014-06-12',
        editable: true,
        events: function(start,end,callback){
            var mydata = {
                    action: "fw_ajax_callback",
                    subaction: "get_myappointments",

                };
                    $.ajax({
                    url :ajax_url,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: mydata,
                    dataType: 'json',
                        success:function(appointments){
                            var events = [];
                            if(!!appointments){
                                $.map( appointments, function( r ) {
                                    events.push({
                                        title: r.title,
                                        start: r.start,
                                        end: r.start
                                    });
                                });
                            }
                            callback(events);
                        }

                })
        }
    });
```

From my console I found an error stating callback is not a function.Please help me i am a newbie.

Comment: From the error it seems obvious you need to have a callback function. The [docs](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/) show a few callback functions in `()`. So may be you need to choose the one that is appropriate for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are making what is supposed to be easy look very complex: I have added a [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/1fda25g1/1/) to show you how it work.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        //theme: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultDate: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
        editable: true,
        events: {
            url: 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/ccUKVDYErS?indent=2',
            error: function() {
                $('#script-warning').show();
            },
            success: function(){
                alert("successful: You can now do your stuff here. You dont need ajax. Full Calendar will do the ajax call OK? ");   
            }
        },
        loading: function(bool) {
            $('#loading').toggle(bool);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: but I am using Fullcalendar in wordpress.Will it call ajax directly in wordpress?

Comment: I am not too familiar with wordpress but fullcalendar is a javascript implementation (client side) while wordpress is a server side implementation. Hence fullcalendar is not dependent on the environment as long as you can run JQuery which depends on javascript: YES it will call ajax in wordpress once you pass the right parameters

Comment: @user3431651 lets me know if it workout for or you need further assistance.

Comment: thanks bro! I got it.I got reference from  [here](http://www.noeltock.com/web-design/wordpress/events-custom-post-types-fullcalendar-json-wordpress/)

Comment: I need a help,will it be able to change the color of past event from current date.

Comment: Do you mean past event from future events?

Comment: That will surely be possible give me sometime

Comment: @user3431651 I got the solution you want now. I found the question very interesting but for the benefits of others who will also also like to benefit from it can you please ask this as a separate question and maybe send me the link here? It will not be searchable if I should drop it here.

Comment: Here is my new [Question link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25452968/full-calendar-differentiate-past-events-from-future-events). Thanks in advance bro :)