# can i put schedule in fullcalendar as ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, fullcalendar

I want to add the ability to schedule in fullcalendar, Laravel. The method is working as expected however, I do not understand what to do with the response data.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
        left : 'today, prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right : '',
      },
        locale:'ko',
        height:'parent',
        events : function(start, end, timezone, callback){
            var month = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate').format('YYYY-MM');
            var url = '{{route('reservation.get_schedule',[request()->id])}}';
            alert(url)
            $.ajax({
                type : 'get',
                data : {'date' : month},
                url : url,
                datatype : 'json',
                success : function(data){
                    console.log(data); // How do I use the data
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fullcalendar - How to load all events on calendar using ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25444930/fullcalendar-how-to-load-all-events-on-calendar-using-ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) for events-as-a-function says:

> [The function]... will also be given `callback`, a function that must be called when
>   the custom event function has generated its events. It is the event
>   function’s responsibility to make sure callback is being called with
>   an array of Event Objects.

There's also an example on that page where the callback function is employed to pass the event data returned from the AJAX call into fullCalendar.

So in your case (assuming that your event data is already in the format required by fullCalendar and doesn't need any transformation) you would simply add a call to this function inside your "success" callback:

```
events : function(start, end, timezone, callback){
  var month = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate').format('YYYY-MM');
  var url = '{{route('reservation.get_schedule',[request()->id])}}';
  alert(url)
  $.ajax({
    type : 'get',
    data : {'date' : month},
    url : url,
    datatype : 'json',
    success : function(data){
      console.log(data);
      callback(data); //pass the event data to fullCalendar via the provided callback function
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'myxmlfeed.php',
        dataType: 'xml',
        data: {
            // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
            start: start.unix(),
            end: end.unix()
        },
        success: function(doc) {
            var events = [];
            $(doc).find('event').each(function() {
                events.push({
                    title: $(this).attr('title'),
                    start: $(this).attr('start') // will be parsed
                });
            });
            callback(events);
        }
    });
}
```

});

[DOC](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function)

Comment: you should explain your answer, and also make it relevant to the person asking by putting it into the context of their own code, not just copying and pasting a generic example from the documentation. Just making another copy of something the OP clearly didn't understand isn't going to help them understand it, unless you add some explanation/.